# How to make a javascript/ajax heavy website render in an iframe?

Tags: ajax, django, iframe

I created a django website, which only has a homepage. However, this homepage is quite dynamic via heavy usage of js/ajax. In my homepage I added to the head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">
```

So I can render this page in an iframe on another website. However, the iframe just gives a blank/white box. How can I get the website to render in an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out response header `X-Frame-Options` (seems to be a `SAMEORIGIN`). If so  `@xframe_options_exempt()` from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/clickjacking/) should help.